# CIFAR10 use only 2 feature instead 10 Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I would like to train a CNN in tensorflow with CIFAR10 dataset that contain 10 categories of images:

```
airplane, automobile, bird, cat, deer, dog, frog, horse, ship, and truck.
```

My question is : can i train my CNN with only 2 categories of this dataset? 
If it's possible, i would like an explanation. 
Thanks in advace

Comment: Ofcourse you can, you only need to separate your training/validation/test sets accordingly to only contain images of those 2 categories. Ofcourse, don't expect the CNN to detect `airplane`s if you only train it with `ship, truck`.

Comment: How can i separate the training/validation/test sets? What do you need to separate? I have to go in the dataset and delete all the image of the other categories??? I don't understand this point, sorry.